# What about highly upvoted VLQ answers?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers, specific-answer

I've come across [this (now-deleted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542897/lightweight-alternatives-to-jquery-ui-sliders/11542996#11542996):

> Try this http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

It's a link-only answer to an off-topic question but is sitting at +10 upvotes (+7 as of now). That makes it unflaggable as "Very low quality". But it is very much very low quality in my opinion.

What does one do in such a case besides raising that on meta? I feel like a moderator flag is not appropiate here.

Comment: What about it? Well, the *real problem* there is the question, and it looks like that has already been handled (it is closed as off-topic). Although that closure just happened recently, it can't be the result of the Meta effect, since it happened ~9-10 minutes before this question was posted.

Comment: I don't see any [jquery] in your profile, are you just blindly *assuming* that it is low-quality?  What **exactly** is wrong with the linked web page?  The post by @Yaniv is not link-only, do you prefer it?

Comment: @CodyGray You still have a user with a +10 score for whats essentially tosh.

Comment: @HansPassant The question is off topic. And Link-only answers of any kind are grounds for beeing deleted (and usually heavily downvoted before). An answer beeing link only (and as answer to a software recommendation question) is almost LQ by definition. Hell, one of the pre-canned "recommend deletion" comments from the LQP Queue is "Link-only answer (and not spam)"

Comment: That's all rather too little too late, it did not get closed when it was asked and 12 programmers found the answer useful.  Why it has to be deleted after 4 years, just because you googled "try this", is not very clear.

Comment: @HansPassant Isn't that obvious? Its a low quality answer to a low quality question which is noise among good Q/A on SO. For the same reason that we'd delete it if it was posted yesterday, we should delete it now.

Comment: It is still not obvious to me why you think the answer is LQ.  What **exactly** is your criticism of the linked web page content?  Why can't you edit the post?

Comment: @HansPassant My criticism is that its a link-only answer. And I can't edit the post because its a off topic question where no other answers are possible really. Like I said, both Q and A are just bad here.

Comment: So you have absolutely no idea whatsoever whether the post is unhelpful to [jquery] programmers or not.  You'd be happy to delete a valuable post just because it looks "wrong".  That's a very dangerous attitude, do us all a favor and click Skip please.

Comment: @HansPassant Quoting from the [answer bans](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) help page: _Provide context for links. Link-only answers are not good answers._ This might indicate you that why Magisch might thought it is a LQ answer.

Comment: How about if a jquery guy puts some context around that answer with an edit so it is not a [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Comment: @keyess - He thought it was an LQ answer only because he does not know enough about the subject to judge its technical merit. Answers that get 12 upvotes from users that *do* know the subject are not generally rated as poor answers here. Any such answer can be improved if necessary with a trivial edit, it just takes a user that knows the subject and cares enough.

Comment: @HansPassant A link only answer can never be anything other then Low Quality and delete worthy. I don't need to know anything about JQuery to see that.

Comment: For non-10k users, would a 10k user consider quoting the (now) deleted answer in the question please?

Comment: @Magisch you do know it's not a link-only answer, right? (as per the [shog guideline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer))

Comment: @eis : _If link isn't spam, it's to some broadly-related resource that the answerer found by pressing "I'm feeling lucky" when googling the question's title._ No mention of why it recommends this, or even what exactly that does, in the question itself.

Comment: The answer certainly could be better. That does not make it a link-only-answer or not an answer though.

Comment: @eis What is not link only about this?  You consider *try this **link**.* to be more than just a link?

Comment: Is the end result the correct result??, the question is closed, the link is a comment... seems fine to me.

Comment: Let's keep comments on-topic and constructive please...

Comment: @NathanOliver the fact that it's apparently the official link to that library, which also contains the name of the library in the link makes a big difference. This is far more helpful than the link-only answers that are really problematic: the ones that point to some blog like `http://example.com/post/2008/10/01/how-i-fixed-my-problem-when-programming-today`. So-called "link-only" answers that give you the name of a tool/library can actually be fairly useful (leaving aside the problem of questions asking for such recommendations).

Comment: hmm but as soon as the link breaks, the entire answer will be useless - with a description the reader would at least know what query to use on google...

Comment: @Rhayene It's fairly easy to guess that nouislider is the right thing to search for from that link, even if it's broken.

Comment: An answer is link-only if and only if the answer contains ZERO information without a functioning link. That is not true in this case, as the answer clearly indicates something called "nouislider" is the solution. The answer might still be poor, but it isn't link-only and shouldn't be closed for only that reason.

Comment: @Bruno I can't judge that one, as I don't know this tool and the linked Website. But a link can still be confusing if a domain has similar sounding resources (like https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changelog-plugin/index.html or http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/ )

Comment: @Rhayene I'd say it's not hard to work out that one is for `maven-changelog-plugin` and the other one is for `maven-changes-plugin`. It's quite visible from the URL. I'm not sure adding the name as a link title would help much more. Then, it's a matter of googling the right name if the link is down (although again, maven.apache.org/plugins is fairly "canonical" as far as these plugins are concerned are anyway).

Comment: @Bruno They are both change-log plugins with different flavour - if the given link was broken and I search and get 2 different plugins - without a description I could not know wich one was meant. (I certainly was confused with these two as I got both when searching for "change-log plugin") but maybe thats a beginner-only problem.

Comment: @Rhayene You'd now which one is meant by the name in the URL, which also happens to be its artifactId (`maven-changelog-plugin` for one, and `maven-changes-plugin` for the other). I agree explanations would help regarding what to do with that plugin, but there's no particular ambiguity in terms of identification here. The fact that there's a number of Maven plugins with similar names and purposes is a different problem. If an answer is a link to one of them, that's the name that is suggested by that answer.

Comment: @Bruno So the consensus is that "go to google and look for tool abc"- answers (which it is after the link is broken) are ok? As a newbie I'm sometimes confused of what is ok and what is not ok here...

Comment: @Rhayene I don't think what I'm saying is the consensus. My point is that some people here complain that "*You can do this with `maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin`*" is unacceptable because "link-only", but at the same time, they'd be fine with "*You can do with with the `maven-changes-plugin` plugin*", even though they essentially carry the same information. Essentially, some people hunt for links for the sake of it, failing to recognise that such links actually carry some important information. That doesn't make them great answers either way, but they can still be useful.

Comment: ... Talking about Maven, a "link-only" answer to a codehaus plugin can still be of some use in that it will give you the plugin name, even if the link is down.

Comment: @Bruno I see - thank you for taking your time explaining. I second you that both variants are not nice. But before I tought that both are more a comment instead of an answer. But I guess it depends on the context the actual question gives.

Comment: I think some people are forgetting here that, if the link breaks, it's because the project has gone defunct. In which case the answer does lose its value, but that's not the fault of the poster. I could have posted an in-depth answer that thoroughly extols the virtues of this solution, why it is better than the alternatives, sample code on how to use it, etc. etc., and if the project evaporates, my answer also becomes useless.

Comment: @CodyGray and thats exactly why answering software recommendations is bad and they should be closed and deleted as off topic instead.

Comment: Sure, I agree with that. That's what confused me from the beginning. The question sucks, it was rightly closed. Next step is deletion, now done. Why the hand-wringing about one of the answers? It is a problem that solves itself once the question is blown away.

Comment: @CodyGray Failing the mass attention this got on meta, the answer and question would still both remain up, only closed, with high vote totals. Its also more about the principle. Link only answers are VLQ, but what do you do about such that are upvoted? Serge's answer details a solution to that, which is why I accepted it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

IMHO, the point is that OP honestly needed some hints for finding an external tool or library. He asked on SO because he knew that there were experts around, and someone decided to give him a hint - for that a link is actually enough. The hint effectively had value for some readers and got some upvotes (12 for 6 downvotes)

But questions asking for software recommendations are explicitly off topic, because usually they attract low quality answers: link only or opinion only posts.

So what should you do with questions and answers like these?

- vote to close the question because it is off topic and the real cause of the problem
- flag the answer as link-only

Mods will take care of the link-only answer (Martijn converted it to a comment) and the question will soon be closed by the community (this one was almost as soon as signalled on meta)

Comment: Don't forget to downvote, though.

Comment: Even as a software tool or recommendation, it is a bad one: you could easily describe the tool and why it is appropriate and its pros and cons.  A link is, well, just a link.

Comment: "But questions asking for software recommendations are explicitly off topic, because usually they attract low quality answers" - if this is the logic for flagging high quality answers to such questions, something is wrong :)

Comment: bang, bang, bang -here i go again. i *get* that the SO community want empirical answers to unweildy questions (hint - it ain't necessarily SO!!). I just find that this whole bandwagon has become a point scoring gun toting mess and as such, I seldom interact in the ways I did only a handful or 5 years ago. truth be told, the fun has left the building and it's aggressively pursuing the same relentless course as we speak. I LIKE to find answers that give me a highlight guide, with a more substantial (if required) link to a more godly solution. anyway, oh for the good ol days :)

Answer (score 12):

I was going to post another comment, but I think it's time to just bite the bullet and post an answer. Judging by appearances, it won't be a popular one, but it is nevertheless the correct one.

First things first—the problem here is the question. It is a straight-up recommendation question. And one of the problems with these types of questions is precisely that they invite this type of link-only answer. So if we want to address the root of the problem, we address the question(s) that are attracting such answers.

And I think we *are* addressing that problem. It is not only part of an official policy that open-ended recommendation questions are off-topic here. That it is a commonly-known community norm is also evidenced by the fact that that particular question has been closed by 5 members of the community for precisely that reason. As I pointed out in a comment above, that closure happened about 10 minutes *prior* to this question being posted on Meta, so it cannot have been the "Meta effect" that was responsible for its closure.

Now that the question has been closed, it can't attract any more of these answers, so the problem has been addressed at its source.

As far as the answer itself, I'll agree it isn't the best answer I've ever seen. But it *is* an answer. It *does* answer the question. The question asks for a lightweight alternative to jQuery UI sliders, and Ryan's answer, by all objective standards, recommends a lightweight alternative to jQuery UI sliders. It meets all of the standards enumerated in the question, namely that it is lightweight because it does not use jQuery and that it allows the creation of a bar with a draggable knob.

I know what you're thinking—but…but…it's still *a bad answer*. Well, yes. Because it's an answer to a bad question. But it *is* an answer.

And don't take my word for it. Shog spent hours working on [this thingy about apples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) that tries to explain what the criteria for answers are. I'll be the first to admit I don't really understand all of it, but it seems pretty clear to me that there exists such a thing as link-only answers that are answers. Look at his two examples, one a link to the documentation for a `FileOutputStream` and the second a link to the manual for `preg_split`. Both are very short and contain pretty much just a link, but they do nevertheless convey information that is subject to answering the question.

In this case, the answer *did*, as we've already established, answer the question. Moreover, the community of [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and [slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slider) experts has already established via voting that this is a useful answer. You are complaining that it is not, but you are going about it precisely backwards. Standards have been established to help us judge, independent of context, what a good answer is. They aren't needed in this case, because we already *have* context that establishes whether or not it is a useful answer.

Beyond all of that, it seems like the underlying concern here is one of reputation.

> You still have a user with a +10 score for whats essentially tosh.

So what? They got magic Internet points? Great, with the 10 points they earned from that answer and $5, they can buy a cup of coffee.

Comment: Cody, were one to hang out on 10k tools and focus on New Answers to Old Questions and use their 100 flags a day with NAA, they may experience a 100% success rate. It has happened regardless of OP rep.

Comment: I don't know what your point is, @Drew. There are lots of bad answers on the site. I'm no stranger to them. I used to use my full allotment of 100 flags, then I realized it was a waste of my time, like trying to empty water out of a sinking ship with a teacup. Conscientious folks who care about quality are outnumbered by several orders of magnitude, and regular users aren't provided with enough tools to solve the problem. Nevertheless, the existence of lots of bad answers on the site has little to do with this particular answer.

Comment: I too used to. My point is what I said. It is NAA flag-able and successful at that.

Comment: Then what the heck is this question about? Magisch should have just flagged it and gone on with his day.

Comment: I, ah, tend to agree.

Comment: @CodyGray Is your comment saying that caring about quality is a waste of time?

Comment: It is expressing frustration that there is only a small subset of people who care about quality, vastly outnumbered by the people who care only about themselves. And in the fact that the site administrators no longer seem to care about the quality problem as long as the site is "successful" by whatever metrics they're using (participation, ad revenue, etc.)

Comment: @CodyGray Funny you argued that, I argued the same a while ago and shog refuted my insinuation heavily.

Comment: Shog is one of the few who actually cares. I don't know how he does it. His dedication and good cheer never cease to amaze me.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, of course, if everyone who has the power and the tools to tackle the problem of NAA and VLQ answers and handle them as they come do **not** use it, then it is a lost cause. We have the tools. We just need the people. And saying "not my problem, there's too much anyway" isn't helping.

Comment: "So what? They got magic Internet points? Great, with the 10 points they earned from that answer and $5, they can buy a cup of coffee." This is maybe a bit weak point of this overall nice answer. In the end, it seems quite a lot of users of Stackoverflow care about this magic internet points. One cannot just ignore this if it isn't convenient.

Comment: @Tunaki as long as the system (bad audits, declined flags) punishes people for trying to care about the quality, people won't care about the quality.

Comment: "*So what? They got magic Internet points?*" Thank you for posting this in particular. Way, *way* too much is being made of the fact that something of dubious quality managed to be upvoted. That's been happening since Day 1 of SO, and it isn't going away anytime soon. Deal with it.

Comment: @Tunaki: "*We have the tools. We just need the people.*" Then maybe you need to re-evaluate why people come to SO. It's not to be curators. It's not to use the review queue and whatnot. Most of us are here because we like *answering questions*. We have expertise, and we like sharing it. We like thinking about problems and solving them. We enjoy learning new things by solving such problems, or looking up facts that we might not have bothered with otherwise. If doing crapwork on my free time is what it takes to do civic duty by SO standards... then I'm not going to be a good citizen.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is your opinion. But when the site is flooded with NAA and VLQ answers and you aren't moderating them, it will fall. And then you won't be able to come to SO because there will be nothing to come back to. Moderation is the number 1 rule to cohesion and making things work. You can close your eyes but that doesn't change the result. Good citizen don't like the police, they just want to out on the street and don't think about muggers but if they weren't there, can you imagine what would happen? (okay it's a long stretch but still, the point stands).

Comment: @Tunaki: "*But when the site is flooded with NAA and VLQ answers and you aren't moderating them, it will fall.*" Um, why? Question quality is far more important in the long run than answer quality. "*Good citizen don't like the police*" Your analogy fails because you're saying that a citizen isn't good if they aren't *the police*.

Comment: @NicolBolas "*Your analogy fails because you're saying that a citizen isn't good if they aren't the police*" I didn't say that. Where did I say that?

Comment: @Tunaki There's a lot of grey areas. As an active answerer, I'm very keen on clear, on-topic questions, and I agree moderation is important. As a consumer, I'm not so bothered whether the answer that helps me (e.g. if I'm looking for alternative sliders) fits exactly the quality criteria. Link-only answers that are a link to the right function/library that answer the question directly are actually fairly useful. In addition, digging up 3-year old questions for the sake of it seems like a waste of time. OK, a new answer was added a few hours ago after 3 years, but is it really such a nuisance?

Comment: @Tunaki In addition to what Nicol has already said, my point is simply that it is like pissing in the ocean. I can go through and use all of my close votes and maybe see 1 or 2 bad questions get closed. There are too many people asking crappy questions and not enough people with enough juice to handle them. Now that I have been empowered as a gold tag badge holder to mark questions as duplicates, I am doing a lot more of that. It works well: it motivates me to keep the site clean and organized and people get their answers immediately. But duplicates are even less important to manage than crap.

Comment: You get to a point where you care *too much*, or at least I certainly did. I experienced moderation fatigue, a symptom of spending too much time on the site, caring too much about quality content, and expending too much energy on futile attempts to handle it. In the absence of new tools to make it easier and faster to cut down on the flotsam and jetsam, I'm unlikely to find myself persuaded to start running on the wheel again. If you're saying it makes me a bad citizen, well maybe, but I'd respond that a community that requires all of its citizens to be ever vigilant is a badly broken one.

Answer (score 6):

The question boils down to: Can bad (negatively scored or closed) questions have good (upvoteable, high-quality) answers and was this an upvoteable answer?

**What is bad about link-only answers?** They might get outdated and the explanation in the external source might not be specific to the question. Both is not useful.

**What is bad about questions asking for libraries?** They act like a poll and the recommendations in the answers might get outdated soon. Both is not useful.

If something is not useful, a downvote of the answer is appropriate and that is what I recommend.

In this case there simply is most probably no good, lightweight alternative jquery slider that will be generally agreed upon. It always depends on further circumstances. That is what Software Recommendations have realized and ask for on their site.

Comment: Btw. I see such software recommendations often in comments and there I actually am quite okay with them.

Comment: downvoting answers "sitting at +10 upvotes" is sort of... futile (I _do_ vote them down anyway, it just doesn't help)

Comment: @gnat I also do vote on them and I believe that it somehow works but very slowly. Voting is the core of SO, isn't it. The only way to accelerate I know of is the meta effect.

Comment: "*the explanation in the external*" I think we can distinguish two types of link-only answer. This particular case isn't about providing a link to external explanations, rather it's a link (and the name) of a potential solution. It's certainly much more stable than some random explanation in principle (as long as that library is reasonably maintained). While these are not great questions on SO, perhaps there should be a path to migrate these type of questions to Software Recommendations, so as not to lose those potentially useful pieces of information.

Comment: @Bruno People here seem to be very cautious with migrating anything to Software Recommendations although I regularly see quite a number of questions I often think would be great to have on Software Rec. But then I also think that instead of migrating the easiest way might be to just ask the question again on Software Rec. Chances are great the answers are outdated quite a lot anyway and Software Rec always ask for more specifications which is better anyway.

Comment: Software Recommendations (nor any other site) wants to be on the receiving end of crappy questions that Stack Overflow has rejected. Opening up a new migration path is unlikely to happen, you'll have the moderators of that site at our door with pitchforks.