# What to do about high voted low quality answers

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

I wanted to figure out how to get the size of a GH repo and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646517/see-the-size-of-a-github-repo-before-cloning-it).

I noticed that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646517/see-the-size-of-a-github-repo-before-cloning-it/38752347#38752347) just recommended a Google Chrome extension. Although it *did* answer my question, I have learned though VLQ review and MSO posts that such answers are not supposed to be here. Am I wrong?

I was going to flag it as LQ, but I couldn't (I assume because of it's high score?).

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: In what universe is that a "link-only answer"? I see text, images, and links. What would you change about that answer if you could?

Comment: For cases where the answer is really low quality: [What about highly upvoted VLQ answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316415/what-about-highly-upvoted-vlq-answers?rq=1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have learned though VLQ review and MSO posts that such answers are not supposed to be here. Am I wrong?

Yes, you are.  Suggesting a product that will solve a question that is asked and describing how to use it to solve that problem is a perfectly acceptable answer, so long as you do so in such a way as to avoid the rules around spam.

> What is the best way to deal with this?

Apparently you thought that the answer was useful, so vote accordingly.  There's nothing else for you to do.

Comment: "Suggesting a product that will solve a question is a perfectly acceptable answer." Not always, some will try to promote their products in answers, make sure it's not pub.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier There are rules surrounding spam, yes, but those rules are separate from whether or not a post is considered an answer, and aren't relevant to the post at hand.

Answer (score 3):

This particular answer is perfectly fine and you could upvote it as you've found it useful.

If that would be the only answer to the question it *may* be considered as low quality as "link only" product recommendation (definitely way more than link so). Even in this case better option (as you've found answer useful) would be to improve/comment on the answer rather than trying to flag LQ.

In this particular case there are other answers explaining other alternatives that does not require any special tools/products. It is perfectly fine and even preferred to add new answer without duplicating information from existing once.

Think if you see the same solution provided as options in first answer - I don't believe you'd consider extension recommendation problematic if offered as alternative to curl / rest calls.